# Não consigo encontrar o erro na minha atividade

Tags: java

Ativ1Data.java:19: error: : or -> expected case 08 : System.out.printf("%d de Agosto de %d", dia, ano); break;

Ativ1Data.java:19: error: ';' expected case 08 : System.out.printf("%d de Agosto de %d", dia, ano); break;

Ativ1Data.java:20: error: : or -> expected case 09 : System.out.printf("%d de Setembro de %d", dia, ano); break;

Ativ1Data.java:20: error: ';' expected case 09 : System.out.printf("%d de Setembro de %d", dia, ano); break;

4 errors

Estou tendo esses erros nesse código que fiz para uma atividade mas não faço ideia por que. Já tentei mudar algumas coisas mas continuei com o mesmo erro no "case 08" e no "case 09". Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado!!

```
public class Ativ1Data {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dia, mes, ano;
    String mes_char;
    System.out.print("Digite o dia: ");
    dia = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
    System.out.print("Digite o mes: ");
    mes = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
    System.out.print("Digite o ano: ");
    ano = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
    switch(mes) {
        case 01 : System.out.printf("%d de Janeiro de %d", dia, ano); break;
        case 02 : System.out.printf("%d de Fevereiro de %d", dia, ano); break;
        case 03 : System.out.printf("%d de Marco de %d", dia, ano); break;
        case 04 : System.out.printf("%d de Abril de %d", dia, ano); break;
        case 05 : System.out.printf("%d de Maio de %d", dia, ano); break;
        case 06 : System.out.printf("%d de Junho de %d", dia, ano); break;
        case 07 : System.out.printf("%d de Julho de %d", dia, ano); break;
        case 08 : System.out.printf("%d de Agosto de %d", dia, ano); break;
        case 09 : System.out.printf("%d de Setembro de %d", dia, ano); break;
        case 10 : System.out.printf("%d de Outubro de %d", dia, ano); break;
        case 11 : System.out.printf("%d de Novembro de %d", dia, ano); break;
        case 12 : System.out.printf("%d de Dezembro de %d", dia, ano); break;
        default: System.out.println("Data invalida");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Antes de votar negativo lembrem que TODOS já estiveram no nível que eu estou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você usar 0 na frente dos números o Java interpreta-os na base octal.

Por isso acontece um erro com 08 e 09 já que 8 e 9 são algarismos **inválidos** nesta base. A solução neste caso é só remover este zero.

Para saber mais

- Literais numéricos nas [especificações do Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html), seção 3.10.1
- Na [Wikipedia é possível encontrar uma leitura básica sobre bases numéricas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix)

Comment: Muito obrigado!